# Regex to get everything but last chars of capture group

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

How do I use regex to select everything before last 4 char in a capture group?

Example:

```
String str = "{Index1=StudentData(studentName=Sam, idNumber=321231312), Index2=StudentData(studentName=Adam, idNumber=5675), Index3=StudentData(studentName=Lisa, idNumber=67124)}";
String regex = "(?<=idNumber=)[a-zA-Z1-9]+(?=\))";

System.out.println(str.replaceAll(regex, "*"));
```

Current output:

```
{Index1=StudentData(studentName=Sam, idNumber=*), Index2=StudentData(studentName=Adam, idNumber=*), Index3=StudentData(studentName=Lisa, idNumber=*)}
```

Desired output:

```
{Index1=StudentData(studentName=Sam, idNumber=*****1312), Index2=StudentData(studentName=Adam, idNumber=5675), Index3=StudentData(studentName=Lisa, idNumber=*7124)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex in Java:

```
(\hidNumber=|(?!^)\G)[a-zA-Z1-9](?=[a-zA-Z1-9]{4,}\))
```

And replace with `$1*`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MUYgdn/1)

**Java Code:**

```bash
final String re = "(\\hidNumber=|(?!^)\\G)[a-zA-Z1-9](?=[a-zA-Z1-9]{4,}\\));
String r = s.replaceAll(re, "$1*");
```

**Breakdown:**

- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `\h`: Match a whitespace
  - `idNumber=`: Match text `idNumber=`
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?!^)\G`: Start at the end of the previous match
- `)`: Close capture group #1
- `[a-zA-Z1-9]`: Match an ASCII letter or digit `1-9`
- `(?=[a-zA-Z1-9]{4,}\))`: Make sure that ahead of current position we have at least 4 ASCII letters or digits `1-9` followed by `)`

Comment: Works wonderfully, thank you!